# Problem in arduino if run system how to fix

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

Hello i have problem :

state sensor = sensor steps "IF" anyone "steps now = impulse " = all code run"perfect good work im happy" but if sensor LOW a did not detect any motion while loading the code = broke stop all , even if it is at the end close or halfway, it will stop when there is no traffic "" (stage_sensor ==         HIGH)"", i dont have idea how to fix this//

Please help or sugestion

EDIT : There may be syntax errors (is not consistent), but just wanted to present a problem, the system only works under "if" and this is problem, i dont know how to fix

```cpp
#include <AccelStepper.h> //accelstepper library
// #define light
// #define move_sensor
// #define pump_water
// #define fan_blowing
// #define fan_extractor
// #define blue
// #define red
// #define green

const byte limitSwitch_1 = 26;
const byte limitSwitch_2 = 25;
bool switchFlipped = false;
bool previousFlip = true;
int switchCounter;
int newSpeed;
int state_sensor      = 0;  // <--- stage sensor //
int light              = 2;
int blue          = 3;
int red           = 4;
int green            = 5;
int fan_blowing = 6;
int water_pump         = 8;
int move_sensor      = 9;
int fan_extractor  = 10;

AccelStepper stepper(1, 22, 23);

void setup()
{

        pinMode(water_pump,        OUTPUT);

        pinMode(light,             OUTPUT);

        pinMode(fan_blowing,       OUTPUT);

        pinMode(fan_extractor, OUTPUT);  

        pinMode(blue,         OUTPUT);

        pinMode(red,          OUTPUT);

        pinMode(green,           OUTPUT);

        pinMode(move_sensor,     INPUT);

        pinMode(limitSwitch_1, INPUT_PULLUP);  //pin 1 engine (IF touch)

        pinMode(limitSwitch_2, INPUT_PULLUP);  //pin 2 engine (IF touch)

        Serial.begin(9600);

        stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);

        stepper.setAcceleration(100); 

        stepper.setSpeed(1000);

        delay(500);

    }

  void loop()

    {

        digitalWrite(light,        HIGH); 

        digitalWrite(blue,    HIGH);

        state_sensor = digitalRead(sensor_move);

        if (state_sensor ==         HIGH)   // <--- stage sensor IF anyone move = all code run but if sensor LOW did not detect movement all code broke stop all //
  
            {

                digitalWrite(blue,     LOW);
  
                digitalWrite(red,     HIGH);
  
                stepper.runSpeed();
  
                engine();
          }
    }



    void engine() 
  
    {

        if(digitalRead(limitSwitch_1) == LOW)
        
        {
 
            switchCounter++;

            delay(1000);

            newSpeed = -1 * (1000 + (switchCounter * 200));

            stepper.setSpeed(newSpeed);
        }

        if(digitalRead(limitSwitch_2) == LOW)
   
        {
      
            switchCounter++;

            delay(1000);

            newSpeed = -1 * (1000 + (switchCounter * 200));

            stepper.stop();

            fans();
    
        }
 
    }




    void fans()

    {

    digitalWrite(red,               HIGH);

    {
        digitalWrite(fan_blowing,   HIGH);

        digitalWrite(fan_extractor,    HIGH);

        delay(1000);

        digitalWrite(water_pump,           HIGH);
 
    }

    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(red,      LOW);

    digitalWrite(water_pump,    LOW);

    digitalWrite(green,      HIGH);

    delay(1000);

    digitalWrite(fan_blowing,     LOW);

    digitalWrite(fan_extractor,    LOW);

    digitalWrite(green,       LOW);

    digitalWrite(blue,    HIGH); //this blue RGB light "ON" but if sensor_steps "ON" = active cycle , blue light led off

    delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: If you touch switch 1, the motor goes to speed 2, and if you touch switch 2, the motor goes to speed 1? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: If so, on what condition do you want the engine to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is set up a global "stage" variable:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h> //accelstepper library

const byte limitSwitch_1 = 26;
const byte limitSwitch_2 = 25;
bool switchFlipped = false;
bool previousFlip = true;
int switchCounter; 
int newSpeed;

int stage;
  
AccelStepper stepper(1, 22, 23);

void setup()
  
    {
                                        
        pinMode(limitSwitch_1, INPUT_PULLUP);

        pinMode(limitSwitch_2, INPUT_PULLUP);

        Serial.begin(9600);
 
        stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);

        stepper.setAcceleration(100);

        stepper.setSpeed(1000);

        delay(500);
        
        stage = 0;

    }

void loop()

    {  
        
        stepper.runSpeed();
  
        runner();

    }

void runner()
{

    if(stage == 0 && digitalRead(limitSwitch_1) == LOW)

        {  
                     
            switchCounter++;

            delay(5000);
    
            newSpeed = -1 * (1000 + (switchCounter * 200));

            stepper.setSpeed(newSpeed);
            
            ++stage;
 
        }

    if(stage == 1 && digitalRead(limitSwitch_2) == LOW)
  
        {

            stepper.setSpeed(1000);
            delay(1000);
            stepper.setSpeed(0);
            
            ++stage;
        }
    if (stage == 2) {
        // do next thing, then ++stage;, etc.
    }     
}
```

Comment: @MrH4ze Whatever you want to do next. If you want to start up a fan afterwards, this is where you would do the loop to run it.